# Halt DML in Process Builder (similar to a validation rule)

Tags: process-builder

Please advise, I'm writing custom logic like: 'User cannot close an Opp if it has no OppContactRoles'

Does anyone know if there is an action in Process Builder to stop a record from updating? Preferably with an alert similar to apex .adderror() method.

I cannot use a custom Validation rule on my Opp because the logic depends on OppContactRoles (which allow no triggers and no standard Rollup to Opp) so I plan to rollup(count) oppContactRoles using a PB.
Problem is- validation rules run before a PB. Also I like to keep logic in one place, so saving writing a 'Before' trigger as a last resort.
Thanks!

Comment: I think the only way you can do this currently is to write some `Invocable` Apex and throw an `.addError()` based on the conditions you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

I found an old explanation: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005FUoIAM
Apparently this one does not have a solution, as it is not possible to invoke Apex .addError() from inside a process builder. Being too deep in the dream within a dream.